# TinyMCE not working in IE9

Tags: joomla, tinymce, internet-explorer-9, joomla1.5

I have been using `TinyMCE WYSIWYG` in CMSMS(CMS Made simple), its working in all other browsers like FF,IE7,8,Google Chrome & Safari but its not working in IE9,

When i try to update any data and then **save** it, its look good with `successfully save` message but actually its not at all saved my changes.

i'm very much tired by goggling for this issue but get no success at all.:(

i have seen that this is the issue which also occur in **JOOMLA 1.5X**. in joomla if we are suppose try to write anything in **Editor** then all save,apply and cancel button not been worked.

Please help me out from this unusual error.

i appreciate your efforts.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen on the frontend only or both the backend and frontend?

Comment: Actually i have been using TINYMCE in backend only.so for me its happens in Backend only. Thanks

Comment: I almost never use IE (prefer FF) so had not noticed, but this was recently brought to my attention. I had only recently upgraded files, too. But the most recent release of tinyMCE (3.4.7) seems fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark Dexter from Joomla! CMS Development says:

> This is a perfect example of the problems we run into when trying to
>   support a version like 1.5 for such a long period of time. On the one
>   hand, we want to stay up with current versions of 3p software. On the
>   other hand, we want to maintain backward compatibility. These two
>   goals become difficult if not impossible over such a long time period
>   (> 3 years).  Mark

As a workaround you could use JCE, which is using a far newer version of TinyMCE and its based on it.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/88

Secondly you could try manually updating TinyMCE to 3.4.x, which fixes the problem download and extract
 http://github.com/downloads/tinymce/tinymce/tinymce_3.4.4.zip into /plugins/editors/tinymce
/jscripts/tiny_mce

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Just logout from your Admin Console once and then login again..But before logging in,make sure,you change the URL in your browser..
If its http://yourdomain.com, then make it http://www.yourdomain.com and then login..
That should work :)
Another permanent fix for this is;

or you can use more advanced Editors like  com_jce

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

In your header tag and IE9 should emulate IE8.

If that still doesn't work try to get it to render in IE7 compatibility. This is not something I would struggle with I would just turn on compatibility till the next release of TinyMCE:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```